# Saving data in a postgresql database in "inet" and "cidr" format via EF Core

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API and an entity class that contains `IPAddress` property. I would like to save it in the Postgresql database `inet` column. It is a standard mapping as described in the  Npgsql library documentation. I still need to create a unique composite index containing this field. I use the following code In the context class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Switch>()
     .Property(e => e.Ipaddr)
     .HasColumnType("inet");
```

For index:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Switch>()
    .HasIndex(s => new { s.Region, s.Ipaddr }).IsUnique();
```

An error occurs when I run migration creation:

> Property 'Switch.Ipaddr' cannot be used as a key because it has type 'IPAddress' which does not implement 'IComparable', 'IComparable' or 'IStructuralComparable'. Use 'HasConversion' in 'OnModelCreating' to wrap 'IPAddress' with a type that can be compared

When I add a converter

```
public class IpAddressToInetConverter : ValueConverter<IPAddress, string>
{
   public IpAddressToInetConverter(ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = null)
   base(
        ip => ip.ToString(),
        str => IPAddress.Parse(str),
        mappingHints)
   {}
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Switch>()
     .Property(e => e.Ipaddr)
    .HasConversion(new IpAddressToInetConverter())
    .HasColumnType("inet");
```

Another error occurs

> The 'string' property 'Switch.Ipaddr' could not be mapped to the database type 'inet' because the database provider does not support mapping 'string' properties to 'inet' columns. Consider mapping to a different database type or converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-value-converters for more information. Alternately, exclude the property from the model using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Index creation can be added to the migration class in the Up method as I know, but I would like to use the standard approach.

Comment: I was told that the issue is being discussed here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23775